# Erro em import relativo em python

Tags: python, import

Estou querendo testar um código simples em python utilizando o pytest. Minha hierarquia é a seguinte:

```
PythonExamples
    files
        mymath.py
    tests
        test_mymath.py
```

em test_mymath.py, importo mymath como

```
from ..files import mymath as mm
def test_mysum():
    assert mm.mysum(2,3) == 5
```

Na pasta PythonExamples rodo o comando py.test tests, porém recebo a seguinte mensagem:

> Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import

O que pode ser?

Comment: tente: `from ..files.mymath import mysum`, no caso do `mysum` seria o `def` que é criado dentro do `mymath.py`

Answer (score 1):

Tente: 
`from ..files.mymath import mysum`

No caso do `mysum` seria o `def` que é criado dentro do `mymath.py`

por exemplo em uma estrutura:

```
mypackage/
    __init__.py
    mymodule.py
    myothermodule.py
```

o `mymodule.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# Exported function
def as_int(a):
    return int(a)

# Test function for module  
def _test():
    assert as_int('1') == 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    _test()
```

o `myothermodule.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from .mymodule import as_int

# Exported function
def add(a, b):
    return as_int(a) + as_int(b)

# Test function for module  
def _test():
    assert add('1', '1') == 2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    _test()
```